# {{#each pages}} not working in Assemble 0.6.0/Gulp-Assemble

Tags: assemble

I've got my pages correctly pulling in partials and sources but I can't seem to get something resembling a navigation to work using the {{#each pages}} logic.

I am trying to gather up all my pages and output them as a unordered list.

```
{{#each pages }}
<li>{{basename }}</li>
{{/each}}
```

I thought I was following 0.6.0 methodology:

```
gulp.task('assemble', function () {
    assemble.layouts('./templates/layouts/*.hbs');
    assemble.option({
        layout: 'default'
    });

    gulp.src('./src/hbs/components/**/*.hbs')
        .pipe(gulpAssemble(assemble))
        .pipe(prettify())
        .pipe(extname())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Again, everything else seems to work. I don't understand where the "pages" object that #each is iterating over comes from. I've used {{#log this}} and I can see the the "basename" object but I don't see the "name" object.

Comment: I mentioned this over on the gulp-assemble issues, but it looks like you're trying to use the assemble 0.4.x API and context object with Assemble v0.6.0. there isn't a `pages` object exposed on the helper context - but you can access that object inside an actual helper function. Your best bet is to create a custom helper for this so you can render whatever you need

Comment: @jonschlinkert Here's how I solved it. I still don't think it's the Assemble way.

```
assemble.data(paths.templates.data);
//Creating the Sitemap JSON
gulp.task('sitemap', function(){
  return gulp.src('./src/*.hbs')
    .pipe(frontMatter({property: 'meta'}))
    .pipe(data(function(file){
      file.meta.url = '../'+ path.basename(file.path, '.hbs') + '/index.html'
     }))
    .pipe(pluck('meta', 'sitemap.json'))
    .pipe(data(function(file){
      file.contents = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(file.meta))
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.templates.data))
})
```

Comment: everything you want to do works right out of the box with assemble. All you have to do is iterate over the `assemble.views.pages` object inside a helper. We put `assemble` on the `this.app` object to avoid variable conflicts, so you would use `this.app.views.pages`.

Comment: @jonschlinkert thanks again. i swear i'm not obtuse, just new to 0.6.0 and stumbling along. i can see how this would work with a helper. do you have a project in mind that does the same thing or a recipe?

Comment: hey no worries, I hope I didn't imply that! I'm here to answer questions :)